# How to add a node to the second to last position?

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

So I'm trying to make a method that inserts a node at the second to last position of a linked list.

Ex - I want to place 2 in the second to last position of my list of [1,2,3], so my list would now be [1,2,2,3]

I tried the following code, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
public void addSecondToLast(int data){
    Node node = new Node();
    node.data = data;
    node.next = null;

    if(top == null){
        node = top;
    }
    if(top.next == null){
        node = top.next;
    }
    else {
        Node temp = new Node();
        Node prev = new Node();
        temp = top;

        while(temp.next != null){
            prev = temp;
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        prev = node;
        node.next = temp;


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the else statement where you're assigning prev = node, it should be
>   prev.next = node, as prev is the current second to the last, now the
>   node will take its place, so point prev to node and join node to the
>   last node of linked list. Try this, it should work.
>
> first->prev->last, now your new node should be between prev and last,
>   so first->prev->node->last